# C# Barcode encoder for font BC C128 HD Narrow

Tags: c#, fonts, barcode, encode, barcode-scanner

my problem is that the 3of9 bardcode is too long for my string (about 50 characters), so I need to create a shorter barcode.

The font BC C128 HD Narrow could be a fine solution, but i'm not able to encode my string in that format.

Could someone suggest me a solution for encode the string for the font "BC C128 HD Narrow", or suggest me a barcode format as short as possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barcode specifications are strictly determined, so there is little you can do.

All you can do is to reduce the number of dots in one module, the smallest unit of printing.

However, it depends on the accuracy of the printer that prints it and the barcode reader that reads it. Check the performance of your printer and barcode reader.

In any case, small and high-density barcodes can have very poor reading rates.

**In practice, it is better to combine multiple barcodes instead of one long barcode.**

---

If you really want to use one long barcode, you can consider the following alternatives:

- Some barcode readers have the ability, called stitching, to divide and read long barcode and synthesize them as a single barcode.
  If your barcode reader has the function, try it. If there is no such function, please change to a certain model.
- Change to a two-dimensional barcode (PDF417, QRcode, DataMatrix, MaxiCode, etc) that can represent long data in a small area and a barcode reader that can read it.

Answer (score -1):

first of all 50 char is huge. You'll need a good scanner to read that barcode.

Conversion a string to code128 then use a font to make the barcode is doable (see : http://grandzebu.net/informatique/codbar-en/code128.htm).
But I prefere use [Iron Barcode](https://ironsoftware.com/csharp/barcode/) it's a library easy to use that generate barcode from a string. But it's not free for commercial use.